# Fluentd Kafka output plugin config

Tags: apache-kafka, fluentd, fluentdata

I'm trying to use the Kafka Producer plugin in Fluentd (version 0.7.9), first of all I would like to know if the following config looks good:

```
<match log>

 @type kafka_buffered

 brokers mykafka:9093

 topic_key  my_queue

 #how to configure the SASL PLAIN authentication?

 ssl_ca_cert /opt/td-agent/embedded/ssl/cert.pem
 username myuser_here
 password mypass_here

</match>
```

Problem is that I get these messages not getting anyting in the topic:

```
 2019-02-21 10:28:10 +0100 [warn]: #0 Send exception occurred: Connection reset by peer
 2019-02-21 10:28:10 +0100 [warn]: #0 Exception Backtrace : /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/buffering.rb:181:in `sysread_nonblock'

 2019-02-21 10:28:10 +0100 [info]: #0 initialized kafka producer: kafka
 2019-02-21 10:28:10 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2019-02-21 10:28:11 +0100 chunk="58264142c3dc4a2c86869aae9a9a033d" error_class=Errno::ECONNRESET error="Connection reset by peer"
```

Thank you very much

Comment: an example configuration can be found here:

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/fluentd

Comment: Followed this repo, but still have the same "failed to flush the buffer" error...